# Pass an array of objects instead of an indeterminate number of objects

Tags: java, android

I have a function that gets as parameter an indefinite number of ImageButtons.

```
private void addButtons(ImageButton... ib) {
// ...
}
```

So this is perfect if I want to call it for example this way:

```
addButtons(button1, button2, button3);
```

But now it happens to me that I have to use as a parameter an unknown number of objects, for example an array. Inside addButtons the ImageButton parameters are used as an array, so I tried this:

```
ArrayList<ImageButton> ibs = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();
// feed the ibs ArrayList
addButtons((ImageButton[])ibs.toArray());
```

And I get a `ClassCastException`.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the method `toArray()` returns an `Object[]`

You have to use the overloaded method [`toArray(T[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29)

You should use :

```
addButtons(ibs.toArray(new ImageButton[ibs.size()]));
```

Comment: You mean: `ibs.toArray(new ImageButton[ibs.size()]))`

Comment: ZouZou on Android I cannot find toArray(int x), there's not such a function.

Comment: @Beppi's That ? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])

Comment: Thank you, it works!!! I use it.
I still don't understand why, anyway: it clearly states that it's not necessary to specify the array:

"Returns an array containing all elements contained in this ArrayList. If the specified array is large enough to hold the elements, the specified array is used, otherwise an array of the same type is created."

Comment: @Beppi's `toArray()` returns `Object[]` but `toArray(new ImageButton[...])` returns `ImageButton[]`, and addButtons expects `ImageButton[]`

Comment: @rolfl, for that reason I casted it... from another comment I understood that it's not possible for toArray() to return a strongly typed array.

Comment: @Beppi - Casting it does not make it change... any more than `Integer integer = new Integer; String string = (String)integer` - you hve to have the right value before the cast will work... calling a pig a horse will not make the pig a horse.

Comment: Actually it would make a change, as soon as Eclipse wouldn't let me even write it without the cast, because it automatically detected that Object[] was different from ImageButton... , so I needed to cast it, but it was not the correct answer for my problem

Answer (score 1):

Use the overloaded `toArray()` method where you can specify the array type.

```
addButtons(ibs.toArray(new ImageButton[0]));
```

You can specify the size if you want to. If you don't, the method will simply create a bigger array before adding the elements.

Comment: That's smart. I don't need to specify the size.

Answer (score 1):

Due to type erasure, a generic collection cannot create a strongly typed array unless you help it out:

```
addButtons(ibs.toArray(new ImageButton[ibs.size()]));
```

Unless you pass it an array of the correct type, it can only return an `Object[]`.

Comment: Just being pedantic.... the Array-type has nothing to do withgenerics and erasure. This was true before that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(java.lang.Object[])

Comment: @rolfl: Yes, but that's more expected.  You would expect a generic collection to be able to do this (like C# can)

Comment: That is true (it is counter-intuitive that it does not work without the assistance - with erasure the 'intuitive' information is gone though...)